# In Python multiprocessing, what happens to stdout when subprocess exists cleanly?

Tags: python-2.7, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I have a python 2.7 script from which I open a subprocess with Popen with stdout=PIPE and stderr=STDOUT.

After launching the subprocess, my main script does some other work and at a later time, it does a p.communicate() on the subprocess. In the elapsed time between launching the subprocess and calling communicate on it, my subprocess has already finished its job and has exited cleanly but communicate can still read from its stdout. What happened when my subprocess finished running and for how long will its stdout and stderr be open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the bytes on `stdout` and `stderr` are simply buffered up in memory, waiting for you to read from the buffers.  When you call `p.communicate()`, it reads the buffers and returns a tuple of two Python objects containing data from stdout and stderr respectively. When you combine stdout and stderr, as you have done here, the second value returned in the tuple will always be `None` with all data appearing, interleaved, in the first value of the tuple.

You must be careful not to overflow the buffer if the process can produce a lot of output, as warned in [`subprocess.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) docs.

> **Note:** The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited.

Calling `p.communicate()` is also a blocking call, waiting for the process to terminate. After this returns, the stdout/stderr will be closed and the integer `p.returncode` attribute has been set.